# Why Doesn't Clojure provide standard library after creating new namespace?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, namespaces, lisp, clojurescript

I came across this problem after creating a new namespace.

Here is the code:

```
(create-ns 'my-new-ns)
=> #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x7c7c8359 "my-new-ns"]

(in-ns 'my-new-ns)
=> #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x7c7c8359 "my-new-ns"]

(reduce + [1 2 3])
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: reduce in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/pg/bynypsm12nx1s4gzm56mwtcr0000gn/T/form-init1425759900088902804.clj:1:1)
```

As you can see `reduce` function is not defined in `my-new-ns` namespace.

I should be able to create new namespaces so *What would be the best solution for this problem?*

P.S: Also, I'm trying to create those namespaces for my users so they will be able to do whatever they want in their namespaces(the idea is like a container) and creating isolation between namespaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

clojure.core functions are not special in their need to be referred to make them available for unqualified use. The `ns` macro does several things:

- creates the namespace - `create-ns`
- changes the current namespace to that namespace - `in-ns`
- automatically refers all of the clojure.core vars into the new namespace - `refer-clojure`

You can always use the *qualified* form of the core function (unqualified is just less typing), so when you get in this situation, this simple call will get you right again:

```
(clojure.core/refer-clojure)
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating namespace manually and then switching to it, I'd recommend using `ns` macro. According to the doc:

> Sets *ns* to the namespace named by name (unevaluated), creating it if needed.

Also it will [load all public vars](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c0326d2386dd1227f35f46f1c75a8f87e2e93076/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5720) from `clojure.core` to newly created namespace.

So, basically this

```
> (create-ns 'my-new-ns)
> (in-ns 'my-new-ns)
> (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
```

is equal to this

```
> (ns my-new-ns)
```

Update:

Answering your question: symbols from standard library are not [`refer`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/refer)red in newly created namespace, that's why you cannot access them without qualifier:

```
> (create-ns 'x)
> (in-ns 'x)
> reduce ;; throws "Unable to resolve symbol"
> clojure.core/reduce ;; works fine
```

You need to refer those symbols manually by calling `(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your new namespace needs to use the "standard" namespaces to be able to resolve names in them. The documentation indicates that this would be `java.lang`, `clojure.lang.Compiler` and `clojure.core`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are supposed to use

```
(ns my-new-ns)
```

instead. `create-ns` is a low-level facility.